# vscode will not launch, no diagnostics

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code will not start.

I tried `killall code; code --verbose --user-data-dir=/tmp/remote --disable-gpu --no-extensions` (`/tmp/remote` is a new empty directory) to get some diagnostics; however there is no output. It just hangs forever.

I tried running that through strace -f to see if it's something jammed; the bare output is intractable but filtering it to my home directory or to open system calls both yielded zero clues. It's not reading anything in my home directory except for .fontconfig

I'm out of ideas for getting any diagnostics on this. It's really frustrating because it used to launch. I thought I was dealing with a corrupted settings directory, but after systematically clearing its settings to get back to a blank state, *it's not that*. I've been banging at this for two days. There is nothing useful I can add to this. The only internet hit is from 2018 and makes no sense in context.

Answer (score 1):

So my hypothesis that code had damaged its profile was correct after all. I can't explain this, but this finally cleared it.

```
env - code
killall code
env - code --verbose
code
```

What does `env - code` do? Forces Visual Studio Code to fail to start by depriving it of its X session. `env -u DISPLAY code` should work but doesn't. It's got some fallback way of finding the X session but depriving it of the environment variable containing the X security tokens made sure that didn't work either.